# Перезаписать файл исключая нужные строки

Tags: c++, visual-c++

1) Строка которую нужно удалить вводится с клавиатуры, потом нахожу эту строку в файле и узнаю её номер. Введенная строка с клавиатуры имеет номер K.

2)Записываю строки из файла в массив L[], и перезаписываю файл строками из массива исключая  строки K,K+1,K+2.

Я РЕШИЛ ПРОБЛЕМУ, ВОТ РАБОЧИЙ КОД может кому-то поможет...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
int main() {
        string s; // в s считываются строки с файла
        string find;  //строка которую ищу в файле
        int k = 0;  // номер строки find в файле
        int i = 0;  // итератор
        ifstream file("file.txt");

         cin >> find;

    //находим номер строки find
    while (find != s) {
        getline(file, s);
        k++;
    }
    file.seekg(0); // возврат указателя в начало файла

    int size=0;

    file.seekg(0);

    string L[100];
    while (!file.eof()) {
        getline(file, s);
        L[i] = s;
        i++;
        size++;
    }


    file.seekg(0);
    file.close();


    ofstream fil;
    fil.open("file.txt");

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {  
        //записываем в файл все строки с массива кроме k,k+1,k+2
        if (i != k || i != k + 1 || i != k + 2) {
        fil << L[i] << endl;
        }
    }
    file.close();   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Что-то меня смущает это `in` при открытии файла для записи... :) Даже интересно - что значит "не как должно"? и еще - `>>` читает **слова**, но не **строки**.

Comment: В файле все строки состоят из 1 слова.
Изменил на `out`- теперь файл просто очищается


Не как должно в смысле  записывается несколько пробелов и куски строк которые не должны были записываться

Comment: Просто слова - потому что читайте мое последнее предложение - `>>` читает слова, а не строки...

Comment: Возьмите, пожалуйста, какой-нибудь маленький файлик строк/слов на 5 и покажите как он выглядит до и после обработки

Comment: Со считыванием проблем нет, проблема при  записи из массива.
Если я просто ввожу `file<<"hello";` то строка записывается в чистый файл и все ок. А когда записываю с массива то не ок. Сейчас скину..

Comment: Есть подозрение, что проблема в том, что вместо `fil.close` вызывается `file.close`